# Store 'Data' in a HashMap after every Test Execution (TestNG Class)?

Tags: java, testng

Is it possible to store all test cases which have failed in a hashmap, and then call all values stored in the map at the end of a class?

**Variable:**

```
    private HashMap<String, Integer> serverStatusMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

**After Method Code:**

```
    @AfterMethod
public void trackServerStatus(ITestResult testResult) {
    if (testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        try {
            String testName = this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
            int serverStatus = ServerStatus.getResponseCode(basePage.getCurrentURL());
            int i = 0;
            while(i < serverStatusMap.size()) {
                serverStatusMap.put(testName, serverStatus);
                i++;
            }
            //serverStatusMap.put(testName, serverStatus);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Calling the stored values in the map After class:**

```
    @AfterClass
public void sendEmailBasedOnFailure(ITestContext context) throws WebDriverException, Exception {
    String tempTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss").format(new Date());

    if(context.getFailedTests().size() > 0) {
        SendEmailFile.sendEmailReport(
                "TIME: " + tempTime + " | " + this.getClass().getPackage().toString(), 


                "TIME: " + tempTime + " | " + this.getClass().getPackage().toString() + " | " + "CLASS NAME: "
                        + this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString() + "\n\n" +
                        "TOTAL NUMBER FAILED TESTS: " + context.getFailedTests().size() + "\n\n" + 
                        "FAILED TEST CASES: " + context.getFailedTests().getAllMethods().toString() + "\n\n" +
                        serverStatusMap.toString());
    }
```

Look at the last line of code: 'serverStatusMap.toString()'

**Current Output of the Map:**
{}

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have any relation to Selenium. Please remove the selenium, selenium-webdriver and webdriver tags.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Do you want to send an email with failed tests?

Why not using the appropriate features like Listener or Reporter?
Have a look on [the documentation about logging](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging).

Comment: @SeeKing Yes, could be. But I am waiting for feedbacks from the user. I will update my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized variable "serverStatusMap". From below code

```
int i =0;
while(i < serverStatusMap.size()) {
                serverStatusMap.put(testName, serverStatus);
                i++;
            }
```

I can see that i=0 and also serverStatusMap.size()=0. So it will never enter in while loop. so Finally when you print map there is nothing inside map. You need to change your while condition.